# Server Error 500 after adding a custom WordPress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, shortcode

I'm becoming crazy!! I need your help because I'm trying generate a shortcode to show it in the product page, under the product title. This shortcode should show specific attribute. Everything is working fine but when I try to save from elementor it gives me server error 500. And I have to remove the code from the function.php. Here's the code:

```
function add_attribute() {
    global $product;

    $product_attributes = array( 'pa_formato-ml','pa_colore' );
    $attr_output = array();

    // Loop through the array of product attributes
    foreach( $product_attributes as $taxonomy ){
        if( taxonomy_exists($taxonomy) ){
            $label_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
            $value = $product->get_attribute('Formato ml');

            if( ! empty($value) ){
                // Storing attributes for output
                $attr_output[] = '<span class="'.$taxonomy.'">'.$label_name.': '.$value.'</span>';
            }
        }
    }

    // Output attribute name / value pairs separate by a "<br>"
    echo '<div class="product-attributes">'.implode( '<br>', $attr_output ).'</div>';
}
add_shortcode('show attribute', 'add_attribute');
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you checked the error log from your server yet? If so, what does it say?

Comment: How can I check the error? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Generally speaking there's a dedicated section called Error Logs (or something similar) in the control panel provided by your hosting provider where you can get access to these logs. Alternatively, you can also try checking WordPress' own debug.log file: [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).